# Is there a known method to decide auto scaling threshold value?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling, hpa, horizontalpodautoscaler

Is there a known method / keyword/ topic to solve how to decide auto scale threshold value?

Take K8s HPA for example below, I only know I can install some monitoring tools then check memory usage showing on the graph by my eyes to decide a proper threshold value 100Mi. But why not to set it 99Mi, why not to set it 101Mi? I think this method is **too manual**.

```
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 100Mi
```

As I am not mastering in computer science, I want to ask

Is there a known method on solving this kind of problem?

Or what kind of course will cover this problem?

Or what is the keyword to search from academic article?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display this information without any graph you can use `metrics server`. Running it in your cluster makes it possible to get usage for nodes and individual pods through the `kubectl top` command.

Here`s an example where I'm checking the node resouces:

```
➜  ~ kubectl top node
NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
minikube   580m         28%    1391Mi          75%
```

And for a pod:

```
➜  ~ kubectl top pod
NAME        CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
front-end   0m           28Mi
```

You can also see resource usages across individual containers instead of pods using  the --containers option.

I assume that if you use HPA you have this already installed but it's worth to know that If you use minikube you can easily enable `metrics server` with `minikube addons enable metrics-server`. If you bootstrap your server using kubeadm then you have to [install](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) it and configure with all of it`s [requirements](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#requirements) in order to run correctly.

Lastly you can always check manually your pod usage with `exec` into it:

```
kubectl exec -it <name_of_the_pod>  top
```

You can [here](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-best-practices-for-cluster-autoscaler-hpa-and-vpa) for more prod information about autoscalers.